# How quickly does time pass in The Sexy Brutale?

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

Each day in *The Sexy Brutale* runs on a timer from 12pm - 12am in a sped-up approximation of real-time. How quickly does time pass in The Sexy Brutale? How long in real-time does it take for an hour to pass in-game?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes 45 real-life seconds per in-game hour. I timed it myself.

Comment: I can't find any official statements of the time ratio, so the only way you will get a more "reliable" source is if you time it yourself.

Comment: By this timing, a full day would be 9 minutes?

Comment: The math says it's 9 minutes. I have not timed a full day, but I don't see any reason why the seconds per hour would change across the day.